# Tbats parameters into a mathematical function?

Tags: r, forecasting, function

Using the forecast package in R to produce a tbats function on a time series I've obtained the following parameters:

> tbats(cluster1tbattrain)

```
TBATS(0, {1,0}, 1, {<52.1785714285714,4>})

Call: tbats(y = cluster1tbattrain)

Parameters
  Lambda: 0.000277
  Alpha: 0.0004483821
  Beta: 8.149e-07
  Damping Parameter: 1
  Gamma-1 Values: 6.500801e-08
  Gamma-2 Values: 1.250234e-07
  AR coefficients: 0.165745

Seed States:
              [,1]
 [1,]  1.377704557
 [2,] -0.001508431
 [3,] -0.119006816
 [4,]  0.021604901
 [5,]  0.040554704
 [6,] -0.013422482
 [7,] -0.031521559
 [8,]  0.015044923
 [9,] -0.041001689
[10,]  0.032026398
[11,]  0.000000000

Sigma: 0.1353452
AIC: 607.0256
```

How can I turn them into a mathematical function, in the form of Yt=f(α,β,Yt-1,θ), to work with them directly on excel (for example)?

Thank you!

Comment: If this requires `library(forecast)` which has the function `tbats` then you should say so.  Even then, if try to run your first line in R, I get *Error: unexpected ',' in "TBATS(0, {1,"*

Answer (score 0):

You might look at this

```
require(forecast)
data(USAccDeaths)
fit <- tbats(USAccDeaths)
fit
write.csv(fit$seed.states, file = "examplefilename.csv")
```

and then check that opening `examplefilename.csv` in Excel gives you what you expect

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I need to understand how to use these parameters directly on my data. That's my problem.

Comment: Then you might explain your question in more detail.  It originally seemed to be how to get numbers from R into Excel

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. What I need is to understand how to turn the parameters into a mathematical function, in the form of Yt=f(α,β,Yt-1,θ), to work with them directly (on excel for example)?